# Passing data from xcode to php

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode

I have been working on passing a NSString to php file, the result I want to get is to pass a id to php file after viewDidload,so that I can use the id to query the mysql database and retrieve the data. Can someone teach me how to do that? I hava seen many people discuss these codes below, but I am not quite sure what it is about.

```
NSString * myString=@"1";
NSString * post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&id=%@", myString];
NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding  allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/getdata.php"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
```

Do these codes can work on my case? Thanks for your times and suggestion.

Comment: You have some code that seems reasonable to work with... Why not try it and adjust it. Or at least tell us what doesn't work. Also take a look at NSURLConnections class method "sendAsynchronousRequest..." it takes a block as a completion handler and bypasses the "tedious" delegate calls for responses that you might not need as finely grained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I've done the same thing for one of my own Applications:

***Note: This runs a GET request, not a POST request, but it does it in the background and runs efficiently**

Create a class to do the data retrieval from the server (I called mine online.h/m)

**AppDelegate.h**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Faith Life Fellowship Streamer
//
//  Created by David Worth on 7/17/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Math Nerd Productions, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSOperationQueue *queue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *receivedURL;

- (void)stringLoad:(NSString*)str;
+ (id)shared;
- (void)addOperation:(NSOperation*)operation;

@end
```

Add these pieces to
AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize receivedURL;

static AppDelegate *shared;

+ (id)shared;
{
    if (!shared) {
        [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    }
    return shared;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (shared) {
        [self autorelease];
        return shared;
    }
    if (![super init]) return nil;

    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    shared = self;
    return self;
}

- (void)addOperation:(NSOperation *)operation
{
    [queue addOperation:operation];
}

- (void)stringLoad:(NSString *)str
{
    self.receivedURL = str;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"string" object:nil];
}
```

**online.h**

```
//
//  online.h
//  FLF Streamer
//
//  Created by David Worth on 4/30/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Math Nerd Productions, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface online : NSOperation

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* str;
@property (nonatomic) int type;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)url;

@end
```

**online.m**

```
//
//  online.m
//  FLF Streamer
//
//  Created by David Worth on 4/30/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Math Nerd Productions, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "online.h"

@implementation online
@synthesize str;

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)url
{
    if (![super init]) return nil;
    [self setStr:url];
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [str release], str = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)main {
    NSString *webpageString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] autorelease];

    [[AppDelegate shared] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringLoad:)
                                                                         withObject:webpageString
                                                                      waitUntilDone:YES];
}

@end
```

Then in your **viewcontroller.m**, to call it (replace mysite.com... with the URL of the PHP page you want to access):

```
online* o = [[online alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/myphppage.php?variable1=blah+blah+blah"];
AppDelegate* delegate = [AppDelegate shared];
[delegate addOperation:o];
```

And in your **viewcontroller.m** viewDidLoad method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethodToProcessWhatTheServerReturns) name:@"string" object:nil];
```

And then make the method in your viewController.m that parses what the server returns:

```
- (void)myMethodToProcessWhatTheServerReturns
{
     NSString* serverResponse = [AppDelegate shared].receivedURL;
     //Do stuff with serverResponse
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Not very good design. Using subclasses of an NSOperation and a singleton instance of app delegate (why?)just to get the contents of a URL as a string? Overkill and not nice to look at in my opinion, sorry. Or maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Well if you have got something better, share it, otherwise, this method works efficiently and allows for foreground processing of other events. I have not run into any problems using this, and if you simply do the whole stringwithcontentsofurl thing without running it in the background, it hangs your system.